The equation \$ \beta_{e}=\frac{I_{C}}{I_{B}}\$ doesn't apply to a transistor in the cutoff region, right?
I know that that equation doesn't apply to a transistor in the cutoff region, but I don't know why not. Is it because in the cutoff region there is a collector current, namely the leakage current, that can't be accounted for using that equation?

The full Ebers-Moll covers all cases, including cutoff. And that level I version is the simplest/earliest ever made. There are two more Ebers-Moll levels, plus Gummel-Poon and several modifications of it, plus VBIC, plus MEXTRAM. What you have in hand is a cartoon. And asking why a cartoon isn't right isn't a question that can be reasonably answered. (I suppose except by another cartoon. And I'll leave that for others.)

@jack - the mentioned expression is just a ratio of two currents. When both currents do exist - why should it not be possible to find this ratio (what ever the meaning might be).

Another way to phrase the question would be the approximate constant beta = Ic/ Ib only applies where it applies, why? which sort of answers itself

In the cut off region, the BJT has some leakage current possibly in nano amperes. The current gain factor doesn't seem to apply it. So the definition of \$ β = \frac{I_C}{I_B} \$ seems to be for the active region of a BJT.

What are you meaning β to be?
If it shall be a function of operating parameters, then that's simply the most common definition.
If you mean it to be some constant, a device parameter, that simply doesn't work in general (β varies with, well, most parameters), and some region and degree of approximation must be specified for that fixed ratio to apply to.
Which region is chosen for that approximation, is a matter of definition.
The most useful or common definition is probably the linear/active region, but you could just as well choose somewhere in cutoff, or indeed inverted operation (Ib, Ic, Vce negative).

The formula for beta is just one of many ways of describing the observed behavior of a transistor. As long as Ib is not zero, you can always calculate the beta - there is literally no way it could "not apply". You measure two currents, divide them, you get some beta. That's not hard to agree on I hope.
Beta is of course not a constant and depends on operating conditions. As the operating conditions change - the collector current and collector-emitter voltage - the beta can vary by orders of magnitude.
Thus, the value of beta can be always computed when the base is connected and has a non-zero current (if minuscule). Whether that beta is of much use for anything is a separate issue. Just because you can compute the value of beta doesn't mean it indicates the actual current gain of the transistor.
For beta to be usable in typical simplified transistor modelling, it is assumed that it is a linear factor, i.e. if you change Ib by a little, then Ic will change as well, and the ratio of the changes is beta, and won't change very much. In cut-off, beta is very highly nonlinear, i.e. it changes significantly as the base current is varied even by a little bit. So it is not usable with the usual assumption of linearity, but you still can definitely compute it.
